# Вывод информации в текстовое поле. События

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть окно, на котором расположено текстовое поле и несколько флажков.
Подскажите, как по нажатию левой кнопки мыши в текстовом поле вывести в него флажки, на которых установлены галочки? Мой код:

```
from tkinter import  *

root = Tk() 
root.title("modul3.2") 

root.geometry("400x400")

c1 = IntVar()
c2 = IntVar()
c3 = IntVar()

che1 = Checkbutton(root,text="Red",
               variable=c1,onvalue=1,offvalue=0, bg='red')
che2 = Checkbutton(root,text="Orange",
               variable=c2,onvalue=2,offvalue=0, bg='orange')
che3 = Checkbutton(root,text="Yellow",
               variable=c3,onvalue=3,offvalue=0, bg='yellow')

che1.pack()
che2.pack()
che3.pack()

tx = Text(root, width=30, height=30, font="14")
tx.pack()

def b1(event):
    tx.insert(1.0, onvalue)


   root.mainloop()
```

Comment: в чём у вас конкретно вопрос? Не ясно в чём проблема. На каком шаге вы застряли? Ясно как добавить строчку в Text элемент? Ясно ли как узнать выделен флажок или нет? Ясно ли как какое-нибудь действие выполнить по нажатию левой кнопки мыши в элементе?

Comment: @jfs, момент описания функции обработки нажатия кнопки мыши. Как добавить строку понятно, выделение флажка по onvalue/offvalue, не понятно как связать это все

Comment: я не вижу, где вы привязали функцию к событию. Не вижу кода, который читает статус флажков. Где строка, которую вы хотите добавить?

Comment: @yashi, у вас к флажкам переменные привязаны. Читаете из них значения, где не 0 - тот флажок установлен. И разные значения onvalue имеют смысл больше для переключателей - там можно к нескольким переключателям привязать одну переменную и по значению этой переменной определять какой переключатель включен. Для независимых чекбоксов этот вариант явно не подходит.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот, не очень красивый, но рабочий вариант.

```
from tkinter import  *

root = Tk() 
root.title("modul3.2") 

root.geometry("400x400")

c1 = IntVar()
c2 = IntVar()
c3 = IntVar()

che1 = Checkbutton(root,text="Red",
           variable=c1,onvalue=1,offvalue=0, bg='red')
che2 = Checkbutton(root,text="Orange",
           variable=c2,onvalue=2,offvalue=0, bg='orange')
che3 = Checkbutton(root,text="Yellow",
           variable=c3,onvalue=3,offvalue=0, bg='yellow')

che1.pack()
che2.pack()
che3.pack()

tx = Text(root, width=30, height=30, font="14")
tx.pack()

def b1(event):
    if c1.get() == 1:
        tx.insert(1.0, "red \n")
    if c2.get() == 2:
        tx.insert(1.0, "orange \n")
    if c3.get() == 3:
        tx.insert(1.0, "yellow \n")

tx.bind('<Button-1>',b1)

root.mainloop()
```